# Jexcel - Need to add <input type="file" > on change of dropdown in place of last col dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, excel, spreadsheet, jexceljs

Working with jexcel javascript 3rd party library -

On second last dropdown is selected as attachment then Need to change last dropdown column of that row to input file.

```js
$('#mytable').jexcel({ 
            minDimensions: [1, 1],
            about:"",
            colWidths: [ 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
            colHeaders: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'],
                columns: [
                    { type: 'dropdown', autocomplete:true },
                    { type: 'numeric',  mask:'$ #,##.00'},
                    { type: 'text' },
                    { type: 'dropdown', source:['Zip code attachment','Custom attachment'] },
                    { type: 'dropdown', filter: test,autocomplete: true, multiple:true, },
                ]
       })
```

Please help if any one work on Jexcel.